# why is awk not reading a shell array?

Tags: bash, awk

I am using -v option in awk to read in a shell array. However, it does not seem to be working:

```
#!/bin/bash

array1=(1 2)

for i in "${array1[@]}"; do
  awk -v vars=${array1[*]} '{for(i=1; i=length(vars); ++i) print vars}'
done

$ ./program
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `{for(i=1; i=length(vars); ++i) print vars}' for reading (No such file or directory)
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `{for(i=1; i=length(vars); ++i) print vars}' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

why does awk appear to attempt to read a file, not elements of the shell array?

Comment: `${array[*]}` expands to two words: `1` and `2`. As written, your command is equivalent to `awk -v vars=1 2 '{for(i=1; i=length(vars); ++i) print vars}'`. So `awk` understands `2` as the script and `for(i=1; i=length(vars); ++i) print vars}` as the file to read. Hence the error.

Comment: ...and it would not be happening if you weren't violating the cardinal rule of shell scripting: **ALWAYS** quote your variables unless you have a very specific purpose in mind and fully understand all the caveats. `awk -v vars="${array1[*]}" ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass a bash variable into awk and treat it as an awk *array*, you have to stringify the bash variable and split it in awk:

```
array1=(foo bar baz "hello world")
(
    IFS=: 
    awk -v str="${array1[*]}" -v sep="[$IFS]" '
        BEGIN {
            n = split(str, a, sep)
            for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) print i, a[i]
        }
    '
)
```

(using parentheses to localize changes to IFS in a subshell) This
outputs

```
1 foo
2 bar
3 baz
4 hello world
```

Answer (score 3):

Change to:

```
for i in "${array1[@]}"; do
  awk -v vars="$i" '{for(i=1; i=length(vars); ++i) print vars}' file
done
```

`i` do contain the data from the array to use for `awk`
`awk` also need a file to read.

Answer (score 0):

here's an approach for those concerned about typical delimiters showing up in the input data accidentally :

```
 (export __=$'\37\23\373\3'
  
  mawk '__{ __*= OFS = substr(_, split(__,___,____), FS = "^$" )
          } NF = int(sqrt(_=+($__ = ($__)" :: ")) + !__) substr("",
            OFS = ___[_])' \
              ____="${__}"  \
   __="$( printf "%s${__}" "${signals[@]}" )" <( seq "${#signals[@]}" ))
```

> 

```
1 :: EXIT
2 :: HUP
3 :: INT
4 :: QUITQUIT
5 :: ILLILL
6 :: TRAPTRAP
7 :: ABRTABRT
8 :: EMTEMT
9 :: FPEFPEFPE
10 :: KILLKILLKILL
11 :: BUSBUSBUS
12 :: SEGVSEGVSEGV
13 :: SYSSYSSYS
14 :: PIPEPIPEPIPE
15 :: ALRMALRMALRM
16 :: TERMTERMTERMTERM
17 :: URGURGURGURG
18 :: STOPSTOPSTOPSTOP
19 :: TSTPTSTPTSTPTSTP
20 :: CONTCONTCONTCONT
21 :: CHLDCHLDCHLDCHLD
22 :: TTINTTINTTINTTIN
23 :: TTOUTTOUTTOUTTOU
24 :: IOIOIOIO
25 :: XCPUXCPUXCPUXCPUXCPU
26 :: XFSZXFSZXFSZXFSZXFSZ
27 :: VTALRMVTALRMVTALRMVTALRMVTALRM
28 :: PROFPROFPROFPROFPROF
29 :: WINCHWINCHWINCHWINCHWINCH
30 :: INFOINFOINFOINFOINFO
31 :: USR1USR1USR1USR1USR1
32 :: USR2USR2USR2USR2USR2
33 :: ZERRZERRZERRZERRZERR
34 :: DEBUGDEBUGDEBUGDEBUGDEBUG
```

The idea is to use a `4-byte` sequence that's ***extremely*** unlikely to occur not just in text, but in ***ANY*** type of data ...

```
  ASCII control byte : d  31 : x1F \037 UNIT-SEP,
          …          : d  19 : x13 \023 DEVICE-CONTROL-3 (XOFF)
  UTF-8 invalid byte : d 251 : xFB \373,
  ASCII control byte : d   3 : x03 \003 END-OF-TEXT
```

...while avoiding the null byte (`"x00 \0"`), any of the ones that are either `POSIX`-spec'ed (or commonly associated with) single-letter escapes ...

> `x07 - \007 - \a \b \t \n \v \f \r - \015 - x0D`

… the `ASCII` escape byte (`x1B "\033"`), and the last byte (`"xFF \377"`),

having none of the bytes are within **`± 3 bytes`** of any other, including wrap-around, plus the added bonus that for every chosen byte, both

> - `31 / 19 / 251 / 3` (the decimal value of the byte ordinal number, and...)
> - `37 / 23 / 373 / 3` (the same value's octal form being interpreted as if it's decimal)

***are prime***

Comment: where is the 4-byte sequence recommended ?.. any article reference

Comment: @stack0114106 : nowhere - that's just one example i randomly came up with - but feel free to pick anything else that you believe has an extremely low probability of appearing in any type of data, as long as it works for your workflows. i didn't say it was the absolute best approach to things, but at least you can see the reasoning behind some of my choices ( other than the prime part - that was just for fun). the basic approach is simply - pick bytes that people don't remember what it's good for.